# Where to set image cache when using Combine framwork

Tags: swiftui, combine, image-caching

Learning how to cache image with native NSCache in YouTube.

Below is the example code, which is working well. I could see it set the image into cache in `getImageFromResponse` method after data is returned from `URLSession.shared.dataTask`. Well, it is the old way that using the @escaping completion handler.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class UrlImageModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: UIImage?
    var urlString: String?
    var imageCache = ImageCache.getImageCache()

    init(urlString: String?) {
        self.urlString = urlString
        loadImage()
    }

    func loadImage() {
        if loadImageFromCache() {
            print("Cache hit")
            return
        }

        print("Cache miss, loading from url")
        loadImageFromUrl()
    }

    func loadImageFromCache() -> Bool {
        guard let urlString = urlString else {
            return false
        }

        guard let cacheImage = imageCache.get(forKey: urlString) else {
            return false
        }

        image = cacheImage
        return true
    }

    func loadImageFromUrl() {
        guard let urlString = urlString else {
            return
        }

        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: getImageFromResponse(data:response:error:))
        task.resume()
    }


    func getImageFromResponse(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            print("No data found")
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let loadedImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
                return
            }

            self.imageCache.set(forKey: self.urlString!, image: loadedImage)
            self.image = loadedImage
        }
    }
}

class ImageCache {
    var cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

    func get(forKey: String) -> UIImage? {
        return cache.object(forKey: NSString(string: forKey))
    }

    func set(forKey: String, image: UIImage) {
        cache.setObject(image, forKey: NSString(string: forKey))
    }
}

extension ImageCache {
    private static var imageCache = ImageCache()
    static func getImageCache() -> ImageCache {
        return imageCache
    }
}
```

And my app is using the latest Combine framework to download image. I try to add a line in `loadImageFromUrl()`, I think after `assign(to: \.image, on: self)`, the `image` should has a value. However, the console gave me the Error "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/Chuck/Documents/iOS/Projects/Moments/Moments/Model/Url Image/UrlImageModel.swift, line 55".

So by using native NSCache, how or where to set the image cache when with Combine networking?
Below is my code, please give me some hint!

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class UrlImageModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: UIImage?
    private var url: URL?
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    private var imageCache = ImageCache.getImageCache()

    init(url: URL?) {
        self.url = url
        loadImage()
    }

    func loadImage() {
        if loadImageFromCache() {
            print("Cache hit")
            return
        }

        print("Cache missing, loading from url")
        loadImageFromUrl()
    }

    func loadImageFromCache() -> Bool {
        guard let url = url else {
            return false
        }

        guard let cacheImage = imageCache.get(key: url) else {
            return false
        }

        image = cacheImage
        return true
    }

    func loadImageFromUrl() {
        cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url!)
            .map { UIImage(data: $0.data) }
            .replaceError(with: nil)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: \.image, on: self)

        // set image as cache!!
        imageCache.set(key: url!, image: image!)

    }

    func cancel() {
        cancellable?.cancel()
    }
}

class ImageCache {
    var cache = NSCache<NSURL, UIImage>()

    func get(key: URL) -> UIImage? {
        return cache.object(forKey: key as NSURL)
    }

    func set(key: URL, image: UIImage) {
        cache.setObject(image, forKey: key as NSURL)
    }
}

extension ImageCache {
    private static var imageCache = ImageCache()

    static func getImageCache() -> ImageCache {
        return imageCache
    }
}
```

/ / / Update, I found how to do it. Add Combine `handleEvents`method and set image cache in receiveOutput closure fix the issue. Btw, there is more parameters that dealing with upstream publisher & downstream receiver. For me, that needs more practice to consume this new way of networking in Combine.

**Fixed Code**, I also add a subscript in image cache part.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class UrlImageModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: UIImage?
    private var url: URL?
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    private var imageCache = ImageCache.getImageCache()

    init(url: URL?) {
        self.url = url
        loadImage()
    }

    func loadImage() {
        if loadImageFromCache() {
            print("Cache hit")
            return
        }

        print("Cache missing, loading from url")
        loadImageFromUrl()
    }

    func loadImageFromCache() -> Bool {
        guard let url = url else {
            return false
        }

        guard let cacheImage = imageCache[url] else {
            return false
        }

        image = cacheImage
        return true
    }

    func loadImageFromUrl() {
        guard let url = url else {
            return
        }

        cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map { UIImage(data: $0.data) }
            .replaceError(with: nil)
            // set image into cache!
            .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { [unowned self] image in
                guard let image = image else {return}
                self.imageCache[url] = image
            })
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: \.image, on: self)
    }
}

class ImageCache {
    var cache = NSCache<NSURL, UIImage>()

    subscript(_ key: URL) -> UIImage? {
        get { cache.object(forKey: key as NSURL) }
        set { newValue == nil ? cache.removeObject(forKey: key as NSURL) : cache.setObject(newValue!, forKey: key as NSURL) }
    }
}

extension ImageCache {
    private static var imageCache = ImageCache()

    static func getImageCache() -> ImageCache {
        return imageCache
    }
}
```